# How to calculate 2 positive numbers with follow formula

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I need to set the program so it ask for two positive numbers between 0 and 1023. The programm needs to calculate from how many steps can we get from number one  to number two (set by user) if we follow number calculate with following formula:

**Xi+1 = (9Xi + 101) mod (%) 1024**

*I know that if we write 4 as number one and 6 as number two  the result is 722.*

I've been trying wit this for quite some time and I don't really know where I do wrong.

Comment: Can you explain the formula? I cannot see you using 2 variables. Only `Xi`

Comment: Is this right for `Xi + 1`? `def formula(x):return ((9 * x) + 101) % 1024`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = 4
y = 6
counter = 0
while x != y:
   x = (9 * x + 101) % 1024
   counter += 1
print(counter)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 while(pos1<0 or pos1>1023) or (pos2<0 or pos2>1023):
            pos1 = int(input("1st positive number: "))
            pos2 = int(input("2nd positive number: "))

        #formula
        while xi != pos2:
            form = (9 * xi + 101) % 1024 
            xi = form
            st += 1
```